# Shorten product titles on Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, title

I found this code to limit woocommerce product title and its working. But the problem is it applies everywhere even in single product page. How do I make exception not to apply in product page?

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woo_product_title', 10, 2 );
function shorten_woo_product_title( $title, $id ) {
    if (get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
        return wp_trim_words( $title, 4, '...' ); // change last number to the number of words you want
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woo_product_title', 10, 2 );
function shorten_woo_product_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( ! is_singular( array( 'product' ) ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
        return wp_trim_words( $title, 4, '...' ); // change last number to the number of words you want
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: this code also applied in the backend otherwise its working good.

Admin Panel >> Products  >> All Products 

https://imgur.com/a/GrIMKow